# Mysql/PHP How to Select and Order result in a float format?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

Please I have a field **value** (type text) that contains some values (text and also some int or float values).

So I want to select only the float and integers values and order theme by the field **value**.

For the moment I can get floats separately but the problem is that in result I get theme ordered in a text format and not in float or integer format (and it's normal I guess). Example :

```
33
33358
80
88000
90
99
```

Please masters, How could I tell my query to consider results as floats and not text and get instead this result :

```
33
80
90
99
33358
88000
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14):

```
ORDER BY field * 1
```

Or

```
ORDER BY CAST(field as DECIMAL(10,5))
```

Both should do the same thing but the first is easier/quicker to write.

Answer (score 2):

use like the code below

```
ORDER BY ABS(columnname)
```

Comment: what happen if `SELECT ABS(-32);` ?

Answer (score 1):

Storing mixed values in a field with type text is not a good idea. If you want to make sorting and filtering on the field, I would recommend to use them as separated fields - text, int, float, etc.
If you go deep as database administrator, it will have negative performance.

Answer (score 0):

cast VALUE to float/int format when you select that variable in your query and then order the result set by that column.

eg./
SELECT CAST(value as decimal(10,5)) AS customname FROM tablename order by customname

remember, you can cast to whatever you want.